# Display data from one table when a column value in first table matches column value in second table

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I am having a really hard time with this one. I have two different tables namely "departure" and "editor data". I want to display data from departure when the data in "Name" column of departure matches the data in the "ven" column of editor_data.

i've tried the SQL query below, but it doesn't work properly.

```
 <?php

 SELECT Time, Location, Name FROM departure JOIN editor_data 
 ON departure.Name = editor_data.ven 

  ?>
```

e.g

departure table can have either mike or rite in the "Name" field.
So, if the "editor_data" has the value "mike" in the "ven" column then it should only display data related to "mike" and exclude rite's data.

Comment: Your join seems to be correct.   Can you give an example of a row that you are getting in your results that you don't expect?

Comment: Does both tables have a single entry for each name/ven?

Comment: I am getting all data regardless of the condition where I am setting name = ven. It should only return data where name in departure table equals to ven in editor_data table.

Answer (score 0):

Select only those records of departure table where name exists in editor_data.ven column

```
SELECT Time, Location, Name FROM departure where name in (SELECT ven from editor_data);
```

Your issue arises because you try to join two tables based on the column `name` values which is not a PRIMARY KEY. Hence, the join condition fails and it results in a cross join, which returns the cartesian product combination of all records present. Hence, the issue can be avoided by calling a subquery on a selected (limited) list of values.

Comment: Hi, it is not working. I am getting all data. Ii guess some issues with where clause.

Comment: What are the other columns in editor_data table? Can the `name` value be present more than once in the `ven` column of the `editor_data` table ?

Comment: Name is only present in departure table.

Comment: EDIT: I've modified the query. This should do the trick for your need.

Comment: Chandra I made changes to make it working. Thanks.

"SELECT Time, Location, Name FROM departure where Name LIKE (SELECT ven from editor_data where tour_id = '$id');"

Comment: Use '=' instead of 'LIKE'. It's faster with =.         You should've told earlier that you wanted the result for a given 'name' value.

Comment: Thank you. BTW is there any way where I can test how efficient my queries are and then make changes accordingly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84251/discussion-between-sarathchandra-and-rayaan-khan).

Answer (score 0):

So this is how I got it working

```
"SELECT Time, Location, Name FROM departure where Name LIKE (SELECT ven from editor_data where tour_id = '$id');"
```